# Need help to get sql query output like this

Tags: sql-server

This is my query

```
select 
    dtfromdate, dttodate,
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, dtfromdate, dtTodate)) AS NumberOfDays,
    fltspl 
from dbo.tblHR_SpecialLeaveTransaction 
where
    nvrempcode = 'MCL1218' and nvrstatus = 1 
order by 
    dtfromdate
```

Result :

```
dtfromdate              dttodate                NumberOfDays fltspl
----------------------- ----------------------- ------------ ----------------------
2012-05-01 00:00:00     2012-05-31 00:00:00     30           30
```

Another query

```
select 
    dtfromdate, dtTodate,
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, dtfromdate, dtTodate) ) AS NumberOfDays,
    fltcl, fltsl, fltpl, fltcompoff, fltod, fltlop, 
    isnull(fltflexiL, 0) as fltflexiL  
from 
    tblhr_leavetransaction 
where 
    nvrempcode = 'MCL1218' and nvrstatus = 1 
order by 
    dtfromdate
```

Result:

```
dtfromdate              dtTodate                NumberOfDays fltcl                  fltsl                  fltpl                  fltcompoff             fltod                  fltlop                 fltflexiL
----------------------- ----------------------- ------------ ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
2011-01-14 00:00:00     2011-01-14 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
2011-01-17 00:00:00     2011-01-17 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
2011-01-25 00:00:00     2011-01-25 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0
2011-04-01 00:00:00     2011-04-02 00:00:00     1            0                      0                      0                      0                      2                      0                      0
2011-05-14 00:00:00     2011-05-14 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0
2011-05-16 00:00:00     2011-05-16 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0                      0
2011-05-18 00:00:00     2011-05-18 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
2011-05-19 00:00:00     2011-05-20 00:00:00     1            0                      2                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
2011-05-21 00:00:00     2011-05-21 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0
2011-05-23 00:00:00     2011-05-23 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0                      0
```

I need the output like this,

```
dtfromdate              dtTodate                NumberOfDays fltcl                  fltsl                  fltpl                  fltcompoff             fltod                  fltlop                 fltflexiL                fltspl
----------------------- ----------------------- ------------ ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------  ----------
2011-01-14 00:00:00     2011-01-14 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                          0
2011-01-17 00:00:00     2011-01-17 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                          0
2011-01-25 00:00:00     2011-01-25 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0                          0
2011-04-01 00:00:00     2011-04-02 00:00:00     1            0                      0                      0                      0                      2                      0                      0                          0
2011-05-14 00:00:00     2011-05-14 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0                          0
2011-05-16 00:00:00     2011-05-16 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0                      0                          0
2011-05-18 00:00:00     2011-05-18 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                          0
2011-05-19 00:00:00     2011-05-20 00:00:00     1            0                      2                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                          0
2011-05-21 00:00:00     2011-05-21 00:00:00     0            1                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                          0
2011-05-23 00:00:00     2011-05-23 00:00:00     0            0                      0                      0                      1                      0                      0                      0                          0
2012-05-01 00:00:00     2012-05-31 00:00:00     30           0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                          30
```

Comment: Can you please **explain in words** what you want in your output?? Just throwing piles of data at us and letting us guess what you want is not really helpful... e.g. what is the difference between your second and third grid of data?? They do look almost the same.....

Comment: check the last line of that grid....

Comment: I suggest you try the group by clause for this.

Comment: k i tried it but it couldnt get  the exact output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to `union` two queries together. To do this both queries must include all columns, just set those to null/zero as necessary. One other slight difficulty is that you cant use `order by` when unioning, unless you subselect the whole thing.

Without the `order by`:

```
select 
    dtfromdate, dttodate,
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, dtfromdate, dtTodate)) AS NumberOfDays,
    0 as fltcl,
    0 as fltsl,
    0 as fltpl,
    0 as fltcompoff,
    0 as fltod,
    0 as fltlop,
    0 as fltflexiL,
    fltspl 
from dbo.tblHR_SpecialLeaveTransaction 
where
    nvrempcode = 'MCL1218' and nvrstatus = 1 
union
select 
    dtfromdate, dtTodate,
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, dtfromdate, dtTodate) ) AS NumberOfDays,
    fltcl, fltsl, fltpl, fltcompoff, fltod, fltlop, 
    isnull(fltflexiL, 0) as fltflexiL  ,
    0 as fltspl 
from 
    tblhr_leavetransaction 
where 
    nvrempcode = 'MCL1218' and nvrstatus = 1
```

If you need a specific order:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select 
        dtfromdate, dttodate,
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, dtfromdate, dtTodate)) AS NumberOfDays,
        0 as fltcl,
        0 as fltsl,
        0 as fltpl,
        0 as fltcompoff,
        0 as fltod,
        0 as fltlop,
        0 as fltflexiL,
        fltspl 
    from dbo.tblHR_SpecialLeaveTransaction 
    where
        nvrempcode = 'MCL1218' and nvrstatus = 1 
    union
    select 
        dtfromdate, dtTodate,
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, dtfromdate, dtTodate) ) AS NumberOfDays,
        fltcl, fltsl, fltpl, fltcompoff, fltod, fltlop, 
        isnull(fltflexiL, 0) as fltflexiL  ,
        0 as fltspl 
    from 
        tblhr_leavetransaction 
    where 
        nvrempcode = 'MCL1218' and nvrstatus = 1 
) src
order by dtfromdate
```

Comment: A minor warning: derived table needs an alias.